# Python2.7 json loaded text list back into an int list

Tags: python, json, python-2.7

I load a list from a windows INI file via simplejson. The list is read in as a string and I need to convert it back into an proper list so `arr[0] = [30, 40, 80]` and `arr[1] = [90, 255, 255]`

config.ini:

```
Advanced Settings
tlhsv = "[30, 40, 80], [90, 255, 255]"
```

Main.py

```
tlhsv = self.config.get('Advanced Settings', 'tlhsv')
print(tlhsv)
u'"[30, 40, 80], [90, 255, 255]"'
```

How on earth am I suppose to do this? Or even better is there a way I can format the INI file so its automatically read in correctly by simplejson.

I have tried to format the ini differently but having a [], () or comma give a ValueError and explaining nothing. Reading it in as a string was all that worked.

Comment: Sounds like the JSON string should contain `{"tlhsv": [[30, 40, 80], [90, 255, 255]]}` - note two quote marks changed to brackets.

Comment: Can you show us what the INI file looks like, and what the code is to load it? Because what you have isn't valid JSON for what you want (it's valid JSON for a dict mapping a string to a string, but you don't want the value to be a string), but it's hard to know where things went wrong, so you can do the right thing at the right place, rather than do the wrong thing and then try to do a different wrong thing to undo it.

Comment: @abarnert I updated with my real world example slimmed down. I can load ints, floats, and strings but nothing with special characters that are not quoted.

Comment: @jasonharper having double square brackets on lists with a comma and single square brackets on the rest works and json.loads automatically loads them as a list. This is definatly the answer on how to format the ini properly but abhi's answer is the correct answer to turning a string back into a list. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use ast module to do it

```
>>> import ast
>>> loaded_json = json.loads('{"tlhsv": "[30, 40, 80], [90, 255, 255]"}')
>>> li = ast.literal_eval(loaded_json['tlhsv'])
>>> li
([30, 40, 80], [90, 255, 255])
>>>
```

you are having multiple list so it will stored as a tuple, beacuse you cant assign Multiple items to a single variable, So just use a loop to access each item of the tuple.

Comment: If I cast my `self.config.get` with `ast.literal_eval` this works great, thanks! Any way to form my ini differently to not need this at all, its an extra dependency that is not needed anywhere else.